# How is this expression evaluated to false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

This is a demo of the Cartesian product of two sets.

> The General Cartesian product of two sets $A$ and $B$ is defined as $A\times B = \{(a,b)~:~a\in A, b\in B\}$

Basically how i understand this is an intuition from the xy plane, that is the xy plane is a Cartesian product of the set of all Xs and the set of all Ys(all possible combination)

This is an example from a lecture presentation on this (https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse311/14au/slides/lecture09-filled.pdf) 
Slide 18.

My basic understanding of this notation comes from a previous slide(slide 14)
[image]

> The following says "$S$ is the set of all $x$'s where $P(x)$ is true.
>   $$S=\{x~:~P(x)\}$$

In this case, the set of all $a$s and $b$s where $a$ is in set $A$ and $b$ is in the the empty set. 
Is there a logical rule or theorem that simplifies $b\in\emptyset$ to F?  And logically speaking, shouldn't the resulting Cartesian product be Set $A$ and not empty set? If you form combinations of $A=\{1,2\}$ with the the empty set $=\{~\}$, the combinations you would get would be $\{1, \{\}\}$, and $\{2, \{\}\}$ which makes sense to ignore the empty set in those elements and just make it so the end result is $A$, cause an empty set is by definition empty.

Comment: no, because the definition of the Cartesian product is a set of pairs of all combinations where the left item is taken from the left set and the right item is taken from the right set. If you take a Cartesian product of $A$ and the empty set, can you find a pair where the left item is from A and the right item is from  the empty set?

Comment: Careful! You evaluated $A \times B$ where $B=\{\emptyset\}$  and $A=\{1,2\}$. You want to consider $B=\emptyset$ and for that see benji's comment

Comment: also note that in your example you gave $(1, \{\})$ this would be possible if you're taking the Cartesian product of $A=\{1\}$ and $\{\{\}\}$ which is not the empty set.

Comment: Think about what it means for a set $S$ to be empty. It's not empty precisely when it contains at least one element; so it's empty if it contains no elements--that is, if there does not exist an element $s$ such that $s\in S$. In other words, $S$ is empty if the statement "$s\in S$" is false for all choices of candidate elements $s$.

Comment: It can proven that $A\times \emptyset = \emptyset$ for all sets $A$ in the same way that $x\cdot 0 = 0$ for all real numbers $x$.

Comment: @MPW so no combinations can be formed, that's why the result is the empty set

Comment: @benji  {{}} is not an empty set because it is a set that contains the empty set? Kind of confusing.

Comment: @committedandroider exactly. it's a set that contains one element which is the empty set

Comment: @committedandroider That's right. {{}} is not empty, it has an element, {}. An analogy once used here: a brown paper bag containing only an empty brown paper bag is not itself, empty.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There is no ordered pair that satisfies the requirement for that pair to belong to the Cartesian product, so that product is empty.

Comment: @benji there is no such pair. Couldn't you say though that taking the Cartesian product of {1} and {} would just be (1, ) because you're taking an element from the empty set which just has nothing, so a coordinate that consists of 1 and nothing?

Comment: @MPW would it be wrong to say that nothing is ∈ empty set?

Comment: No, but don't say that ambiguously. Saying "Nobody is in the room" means that there does not exists any person who is in the room--it doesn't mean that there is a person in the room whose name is "Nobody". You must understand the *meaning* of the statement, don't get lost in a sea of ambiguous words.

Comment: @MPW agree that wording is a little off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1,{}) and (2, {}) are not in this Cartesian product because {} (the empty set) is not an -element- of the empty set.

Comment: cause you're performing combinations of elements inside A and nothing, which is like multiplying a real number by 0(kind of considered nothing). Is that a good analogy?

Comment: Yes, I think it is.

Comment: Thank you and how is b∈∅ evaluated to false?

Comment: Because the empty set, by definition, has no elements.

Comment: I understand that part but wouldn't the boolean statement be true then because b is in the empty set?

Comment: b is NOT in the empty set, so the boolean statement is false.

Comment: No, $b \in \emptyset$ is false. There are no elements in the empty set. In fact the empty set is often *defined* by the axiom that there exists a set $\emptyset$ such that $\forall y$, it's the case that $\neg(y \in \emptyset)$. So in particular, $\neg(b \in \emptyset)$.

Comment: oh nothing is defined as no element. Cause you can technically say that nothing is an element in the set but nothing is no element.